# Do you have to pay the commander tax if you have an Omniscience in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

If you have an [Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d) in play, will you still have to pay the commander tax or do you get to play your commander completely for free? Or is it the case that Omniscience will only ever make my [Arcanis the Omnipotent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcanis%20the%20Omnipotent%5d) 6 mana cheaper?

Comment: If it did apply, it would only replace the mana cost ({U}{U}{U}{3}). It woudn't replace additional costs (such as the Commander Tax)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commander tax is only applicable when casting the commander from the command zone.

> 903.8. A player may cast a commander they own from the command zone. A commander cast from the command zone costs an additional {2} for each previous time the player casting it has cast it from the command zone that game. This additional cost is informally known as the “commander tax.”

But Omniscience says

> You may cast spells from your **hand** without paying their mana costs.

(emphasis mine)

If your commander has been bounced back to your *hand*, you may cast it for free, thanks to Omniscience.

<sub>Side note: it's rather hard to have an Omniscience in play if [Zo-Zu the Punisher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZo-Zu%20the%20Punisher%5d) is your commander. I thought there was a red card which lets you exchange control of permanents (maybe after a coin flip) but I'm not sure...</sub>

Comment: Ok I realize, the example I gave was a bad one as you could never play Omniscience in a Zo-Zu deck I will edit

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that too...

Comment: Now that it's been mentioned in the answer: [Zo-Zu the Punisher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=80274)

Comment: [mtg:Confusion in the Ranks] can get the job done if someone else already played it.

Comment: Maybe the friendly zedruu just did it's thing?

Comment: @CollinB that is a super friendly zedruu, I want to play in that commander group

Comment: It's me. I'm the Zedruu